# How can I keep a Java program to repeat the same steps over and over for a long time?

Tags: java, http, intellij-idea, server, connectivity

I have developed a Java application that needs to repeat the same steps (sending out HTTP requests and handling the responses etc.) over and over, ideally doing this for weeks or even months without any change. Currently, this is how I do this:

```
// do some preparation
while (true) {
   // do stuff
}
```

The program is able to run for 1-3 days (also depends on network performance) in Intellij Idea on my PC, however, after that it stops.
Can you please tell me the right solution for this, as I am aware that the current one is not professional.

Also, if I run my program on my PC, its performance is severely impacted by the speed and performance of my internet. Would it be possible for me to somehow run my program on a server with faster internet?

Comment: Does your program eventually crash? Or does it terminate normally? Does the JVM process write some kind of crash report file?

Comment: Why, instead, don't you have the application do whatever it does just once and let the operating system (whatever it is, you didn't specify) run the application repeatedly at specific time intervals? (On a related note, running it from the IDE doesn't seems a good strategy to begin with)

Comment: No, it doesn't terminate, it just stops to provide new output. All exceptions are caught by the program and thus it keeps running whenever it encounters one.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca where do you suggest to run it from?

Comment: @cr0078 Generally, you compile the source code to generate an executable and then run that in whichever way is most appropriate. We don't know your program, but you could just compile it and run the .class file that contains your main method, or you could build a runnable jar file, etc. Java comes with built-in commands to achieve all of that.

Comment: "All exceptions are caught by the program and thus it keeps running whenever it encounters one." Well, how do you expect to figure out what the problem is, if you won't allow the program to tell you?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel all exceptions that are thrown are CompletionExceptions, related to the HTTP requests that are sent by the program. However, I believe they aren't accountable for stopping it.

Comment: Okay, so if the program is still running, but doesn't produce any more output - what happened when you tried to diagnose what it *is* doing, using a debugger? Is it stuck in a tight loop somewhere? Does it repeatedly fail to gather input, and thus have no output to compute? Something else? Why do you believe the program *should* continue producing output?

Comment: *"However, I believe they aren't accountable for stopping it."* - Belief is not a sound basis for debugging.  You need *(scientific) evidence* or *(mathematical) proof*.

Answer (score 3):

You have two questions bundled into this question.

1. Instead of running this application in your IDE, package it to run independently. A JAR is probably the simplest path forward. Without knowing more about why it is crashing, this is the best advice I can give.
2. Absolutely you can run this on a server, or serverless deployment. Once you have it packaged to run independently (JAR, Docker image, WAR, etc) you can look at the free tier of Google Cloud, AWS, or other providers to easily deploy it without much overhead.

If you get more specific, I can give more specific answers.